# ¿Por que me devuelve undefined?

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué mi función devuelve `undefined`? ¿De dónde sale eso?

```js
function Maths(){
  
  this.raiz = function(numero){
    if(numero<0) return console.log("No disponible para números imaginarios");
    return numero%1===0 ? Math.sqrt(parseInt(numero)) : Math.sqrt(parseFloat(numero));
  };  
}

var b = new Maths();
console.log(b.raiz(-4));
```

Si intentas sacar raiz negativa, te retornará un mensaje en *consola* que no está disponible para números imaginarios y por ende en el `return`, terminará la función pero además me devuelve `undefined`. ***¿Por qué?***

Comment: Te devuelve undefined, no?

Comment: Sí,  Ivan botero

Answer (score 5):

### Código

```js
function Maths() {

  this.raiz = function(numero) {
    if (numero < 0) return "No disponible para números imaginarios";
    return numero % 1 === 0 ? Math.sqrt(parseInt(numero)) : Math.sqrt(parseFloat(numero));
  };
}

var b = new Maths();
console.log(b.raiz(-4));
```

---

### Explicación

Lo que ocurre es que la función `console.log` **no retorna ningún valor**, por lo tanto cuando escribes:

```
return console.log("Hola Mundo");
```

La función retornara `undefined`, ya que esta función no retorna nada.

---

### Solucion

Puedes hacer un retorno directo del mensaje:

```
return "No disponible para números imaginarios";
```

Para asi posteriormente imprimirlo desde donde llames la funcion.

Comment: Gracias Ivan !!

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Con gusto, espero te sirva, no olvides aceptarla si la respuesta soluciono tu inconveniente. Saludos